# Laravel- use @foreach in markdown mail

Tags: php, email, foreach, markdown, laravel-5.4

I am trying to use `@foreach` loop inside markdown template for sending mails.

While using HTML tags inside @foreach, it is not rendered properly

```
@component('mail::message')

These are the latest contents in our website

@foreach($results as $type => $result)
   <h4>{{ $result['name'] }}</h4>
@endforeach

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

In the received mail, the `<h4>` tag will be displayed as,

```
<h4>Article</h4>
```

Markdown is not getting processed when it's placed inside `@foreach` loop. But it's processed when placed outside `@foreach` loop.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `<h4>` isn't markdown (is it?). I think you need `#### {{ $result['name'] }} ####`

Comment: @apokryfos: the `<h4>` tag is not converted to HTML tag inside the loop. Parsing the `@foreach` content is not properly processed.

Comment: If you're writing markdown then you might not be able to use HTML tags and `<h4>` is an HTML tag not a markdown tag

Comment: @apokryfos: `#### {{ $result['name'] }} ####` didn't work it displays as `#### Article ####`

Comment: @apokryfos: I understood, `<h4>` isn't a markup tag, and Laravel markdown templates work in both ways. But not inside the `@foreach` loop. Please refer: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22290

Comment: @apokryfos: Is there a way to send emails in Laravel without using markdown?

Comment: Presumably you called `...->markdown('path.to.view')` to render this, doing `..->view('path.to.view')` instead should use the default blade rendering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164235/discussion-between-ajith-s-and-apokryfos).

Comment: I have tried calling ..->view('path.to.view), but it gave me an error as `No hint path defined for [mail]`.

Answer (score 7):

As stated in [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#writing-markdown-messages):

> Do not use excess indentation when writing Markdown emails. Markdown
>   parsers will render indented content as code blocks.

The problem is not the HTML tags put inside the `@foreach`, but the indentation makes parsers render as follows (I am using markdown now, 4 spaces before `<h4>`):

```
<h4>Article</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good question, the same applies with an example using markup instead of html. 
For example:

```
@component('mail::message')
# Data received:

@foreach($fields as $name => $value)
    **{{ $name }}: ** {{ $value }}

@endforeach

@endcomponent
```

Can result in:

```
<h1>Data received:</h1>
<pre><code>**voornaam: ** piet
**familienaam: ** hein</code></pre>
```

While with 2 spaces indentation instead of 4 like so

```
@component('mail::message')
# Data received:

@foreach($fields as $name => $value)
  **{{ $name }}: ** {{ $value }}

@endforeach

@endcomponent
```

The same input results in:

```
<h1>Data received:</h1>
<p><strong>voornaam: </strong> piet</p>
<p><strong>familienaam: </strong> hein</p>
```

as intended and explained by @Ben pointing to https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#writing-markdown-messages

> Do not use excess indentation when writing Markdown emails. Markdown
>   parsers will render indented content as code blocks.